# Is there a command line tool for all the incoming traffic in different protocol?

Tags: networking

I found netcat is very useful for listening TCP connection by using -l port-number, but I'm wondering if there is a more powerful tool available to analysis all incoming protocol, like RADIUS client request, so I can check out what the request are made of and if server get the request

netstat maybe the way to go with the -c flag, but it doesn't show even tcp connection with custom port number

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use `netstat` and `grep` the output to filter only the ports that you need?

The output is similar to this:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)    
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.7.63364      64.34.119.101.80       ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.7.63357      64.34.119.13.80        ESTABLISHED
```

and it is very simple to grep results by protocol, port, address and state.

Answer (score 1):

Wireshark offers a command line tool as well as a GUI (http://www.wireshark.org/)

Answer (score 0):

[Bro](http://www.bro-ids.org) is a (command-line) tool that extracts a wide range of information from network traffic. It is port agnostic, e.g., can detect HTTP on non-standard ports and features a application parsers for a variety of protocols. The connection log provides a lot of useful information at flow granularity, including:

- Timestamp
- Connection 5-tuple (source host, source port, destination host, destination port, transport protocol)
- Application-layer protocol
- Duration
- Transport-layer bytes sent (source and destination)
- Connection status
- Number of packets (source and destination)

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10066658/1170277) for example output.